# Calculate total count of two nodes and number of relations between them in single query using cypher - neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a graph with Entities `Customer` , `Product` and Relationship `ORDERED`. Following is the relation between them in Cypher way

```
(Customer)-[:ORDERED]->(Product)
```

I want to calculate total number of product , total number of customer and total number of order in a single cypher query.

Below is the query that I written

Single Query

```
MATCH 
    (c:Customer)-[r:ORDERED]->(p:Product),
    (p1:Product),
    (c1:Customer)
WITH     
    count(r) as order_count , 
    count(DISTINCT c1) as  customer_count , 
    count(DISTINCT p1) as  product_count 
RETURN order_count , customer_count , product_count
```

But it is executing for long time  giving wrong result with all count as same value .

If I execute each count independently then it giving results very fast and correctly

Separate query

```
MATCH  (c:Customer)-[r:ORDERED]->(p:Product)
WITH  count(r) as order_count
RETURN order_count

MATCH (p1:Product)
WITH count(DISTINCT p1) as  product_count 
RETURN  product_count 

MATCH (c1:Customer)
WITH  count(DISTINCT c1) as  customer_count  
RETURN  customer_count
```

Can anyone explain what is going on in the single query ?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is exploding, generating the cross product of the three initial matches. To avoid the cross product you can:

```
MATCH (c:Customer)
WITH COUNT(c) AS customer_count
MATCH (p:Product)
with cs, COUNT(p) AS product_count
MATCH ()-[r:ORDERED]->()
RETURN customer_count, product_count, COUNT(r) AS order_count
```

I do not think you can get all the counts without rematching for the ORDERED relationship. If the ordered relationsip can happen between other types of nodes you will have to add swap the second to last line with:

```
MATCH (:Customer)-[r:ORDERED]->(:Product)
```